# VB.NET - Given a date, how can I get the date of the following friday?

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, .net-2.0

Given a Date, how can I get the date of following Friday (or any other weekday) in VB.NET in .NET Framework 2.0?

Answer (score 9):

```
Dim NextFriday as Date= GetNext(DayOfWeek.Friday) 

Function GetNext(ByVal d As DayOfWeek, Optional ByVal StartDate As Date = Nothing) As Date
    If StartDate = DateTime.MinValue Then StartDate = Now
    For p As Integer = 1 To 7
        If StartDate.AddDays(p).DayOfWeek = d Then Return StartDate.AddDays(p)
    Next
End Function
```

**Edit:** Updated the answer to allow a startdate (optional).

Get next friday:

```
Dim NextFriday As Date = GetNext(DayOfWeek.Friday)
```

What is the next friday after 15 days from now:

```
Dim AnotherFriday As Date = GetNext(DayOfWeek.Friday,now.addays(15))
```

Comment: Make it as an extention to the date-object to have more fun.

Answer (score 9):

```
'
Public Function nextDOW(whDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek, _
                        Optional theDate As DateTime = Nothing) As DateTime
    'returns the next day of the week
    If theDate = Nothing Then theDate = DateTime.Now
    Dim d As DateTime = theDate.AddDays(whDayOfWeek - theDate.DayOfWeek)
    Return If(d <= theDate, d.AddDays(7), d)
End Function
```

Comment: I didnt vote -1, but I think the d<thedate shoud be d<=thedate to be correct. Like this: Return If(d <= theDate, d.AddDays(7), d)

Because If you want the next Wednesday and the startdate is a wednesday you dont want THAT wednesday as result, but the next.

Comment: Noted and agreed, corrected in place.  The loop answers get up-voted, and mine gets down voted.  Gotta love SO.

Comment: You have +1 from me. ;)
This is the "Fastest Gun in the West Problem" in action. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). I think, over time you'll get more votes and it will be corrected.

Comment: +1 for the clean solution... made even cleaner by @Stefan's suggestion to make it an extension to the date object.

Comment: Instead of `If theDate = Nothing Then theDate = DateTime.Now`, you can use the [If operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.90).aspx) with two arguments: `Dim dateValue = If(theDate, DateTime.Now)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim someDate As DateTime = ... 'input date
Dim nextFriday As DateTime = someDate
While nextFriday.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday
    nextFriday = nextFriday.AddDays(1)
End While

Console.WriteLine(nextFriday)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another Variation as those above, just with no loop:

```
Private Function GetFridayDate(StartingDate As Date, DayToGet As DayOfWeek, iDays As Integer) As Date
      Return StartingDate.AddDays(iDays + (DayToGet - StartingDate.DayOfWeek))
End Function
```

Example of how to use the function

```
Dim dtStartDate As Date

dtStartDate = GetFridayDate(Now, DayOfWeek.Friday, -7) ' Last Week Friday

dtStartDate = GetFridayDate(Now, DayOfWeek.Friday, 0) ' This Week Friday

dtStartDate = GetFridayDate(Now, DayOfWeek.Friday, 7) ' Next Week Friday

dtStartDate = GetFridayDate(Now, DayOfWeek.Friday, 14) ' Week after Next Friday
```